# Programming Greatest Common Divisor for HTML Webpage

Tags: html, greatest-common-divisor

EDIT: So the question is, why will my script not execute properly.

Edit 2: So this is the part that works as advertised and all items are predefined as number inputs prior too.

```
        <script>
        function Script5(){
            var numeratorIn = document.getElementById("Numerator").value;
            var denominatorIn = document.getElementById("Denominator").value;
            var FACTOR = document.getElementById("FACTOR").value;
            var Snum = document.getElementById("Snum").value;
            var Sden = document.getElementById("Sden").value;
            var x = document.getElementById("FinalAnswer");
                x.style.display = 'none';
            var x = document.getElementById("FinalDisplay");
                x.style.display = 'block';
        }
        </script>
```

So I am working on a series of codes for a website I will be developing and this is a small subroutine for finding greatest common divisors. I am using Notepad++ for mobility purposes and trying to run my code in Google Chrome to start. I want to make a GCD function for variables (numeratorIn,denominatorIn). Again in HTML

This is the part I want to add into the same script

```
        var a = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(numeratorIn));
        var b = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(denominatorIn));
        document.getElementById("midpage15").innerHTML = (+a);
        var k = 1
        if (a<b) {
            while (k<a) {
                if ((Snum/k == Math.floor(Snum/k)) && (Sden/k == Math.floor(Sden/k)); {
                    var h = k;
                }
                k = k++;
            }
        }
        else if (a>b) {
            while (k<b) {
                if ((Snum/k == Math.floor(Snum/k)) && (Sden/k == Math.floor(Sden/k)) {
                    var h = k;
                }
                k = k++;
            }
        }
        else (a == b) {
        document.getElementById("midpage15").innerHTML = ("Final Answer 1");
        }
```

But it breaks my button that I use to activate the script every time :(

I usually program in Python but I want to make this in HTML. So I spent about 5 hours working on it and it is just driving me nuts. I am 100% confident it has something to do with the Ifs and the while statements at the bottom.

Comment: You didn't ask a question.

Comment: Sorry the question is why wont it work :(

Comment: I see lots of typos here. Fix those and then see what your console tells you.

Comment: see because I have been running this in Notepad++  I am not 100% sure how to run a error check. Everything up to the ifs works just fine, I checked that out meticulously

Comment: got it to work, there was a parenthesis missing.

Answer (score 0):

Here Snum and Sden are string.So you need to convert it into integer first.For that you can use parseInt() function.

Comment: so the bad news is that almost every time I have tried to use parseInt in my HTML coding it breaks my buttons, so I predefined user inputs as numbers to compensate :)